# read Richtext box in sharepoint 2010 visual webpart

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise

From an answer from earlier post to get the first two lines in a rich textbox in sharepoint 2010 in a visual webpart i m using

`var firstTwoLines = String.Join("\n", MyRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n').Take(2).ToArray());`

..what if there is an image starting from the 2nd line..what condition should i use to check if there is an image present and then skip it?

Comment: Do you need to skip only the image tag itself (`<img ... />`), or you need to skip the whole line which contains it?

Comment: hi omlin, i would like to skip the imgae tag itself

Comment: Ok, I added the answer, but can't resist mentioning that the question actually doesn't relate to SharePoint. Please, post pure C# questions like this to StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There may be a less manual way but you could split and then check each lines until you reach the number of lines you need.

```
        int linesInArray = 0;
        int linesNeeded = 2;
        string[] linesOfText = MyRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
        string[] parsedLines = new string[linesNeeded];

        for (int lineCount = 0; lineCount < linesOfText.Length || linesInArray == linesNeeded; lineCount++)
        {
            //This is assuming rich text box images are html which I believe they are
            if (linesOfText[lineCount].Contains("<img"))
            {
                parsedLines[linesInArray] = linesOfText[lineCount];
                linesInArray++;
            }
        }
```

The code implementation itself is a little crude but you could see how you could adjust it to fit your needs and be of more "production quality."

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line after your original code:

```
firstTwoLines = Regex.Replace(firstTwoLines, "<img.*?>", string.Empty);
```

(you will need to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to the top of the file)